# Styling output of database from php loop

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to display data from database and it is important to me that this output is placed on different sides of website. I used php to connect to database, and ajax jquery to refresh data because every 20second values change.

I tried to

`echo <div styles='position: absolute; top: 0px' class='text'>{$row['id']}</div>`

in a foreach loop but when I do this all 6 of my id's are stacked on top each other.

Making `<div>` outside loop was unsuccessful too. I guess my problem is in reading data from database because I read all at once but I don't know any other way to do this except wrtiting 6 connection files to gather only the one value that I want to display and then styling it, but I feel like there is smarter way of doing this.

This is my code. Just want to say this is my first contact with php.

```
<?php
$hostname = "someinfo";
$username = "someinfo";
$password = "someinfo";
$db = "someinfo";
$dbconnect = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username, $password,$db) or die("cant");
if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
      die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}
$sensor_names = array();
$query2 = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"show tables");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){ 
    if($row2[0] == 'sensors' or $row2[0] == 'measurments'){
            break;
    }
    else{
            array_push($sensor_names,$row2[0]);
    }
}

$query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "select s.id, s.sensor_name, max(dev.id), dev.temprature, dev.date  from sensors s, `{$sensor_names[0]}` dev where s.id=dev.sensor_id gro
up by s.id, s.sensor_name order by s.id asc");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ //i konw this is ugly but this is working placeholder
foreach($sensor_names as $sn){

    $query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "select s.id, s.sensor_name, dev.temprature, dev.date from sensors s, `{$sn}` dev where s.id=dev.sensor_id order by dev.id desc limit 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo "
    {$row['id']}
    {$row['sensor_name']}
    {$row['temprature']}
    {$row['date']}
    <br>";

}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is off-the-cuff from a guy who hasn't touched PHP in a long while, so watch for major bugs. But the basic idea is like this: build the code in a variable, and when done, echo out the entire variable. Makes it easier to add the structure/formatting you want. Note that you can also stick in a style tag along with that code and blurp out the style along with the "table" *(Personally, I wouldn't use a table for styling, this is just for demo)*.

Note: I didn't style the output so that it puts the data on either side of the page - I left that for you to do. It's basic HTML - divs, styles, maybe css grid or flexbox. The point is to create your CSS/HTML/PHP mashup in a string variable and output the entire thing when done.

```
$out = '<style>.cell_id{font-weight:bold;}</style>';
$out .= '<table><tr><th>Label 1</th><th>Label 2</th><th>Etc</th></tr>'; //<=== ADDED!
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   foreach($sensor_names as $sn){
     $query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, etc. etc. etc.);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
     $out .= "
     <tr>
       <td class='cell_id'>{$row['id']}</td>
       <td>{$row['sensor_name']}</td>
       <td>{$row['temprature']}</td>
       <td>{$row['date']}</td>
     </tr>";
   }
}
echo $out;
```

Comment: This is close to what I treid, this piece of code returns 6 different data rows and i for example want to have first row in top left corner of webiste, second row on top right etc. Is this possible? By row i meant id, sensor name, temprature, date.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it. Cssyphus's answer got me thinking and I wrote something like that `array_push($data, $row)` and `$data` is two dimentional array that hold all data I need and now I can style it easily.